# ConcurrentModification Exception thrown when inserting the file via content resolver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I created a suspended function that I am calling from ViewModel, the function takes a set of `MyFile` abstract class and then iterates through the set to get values and eventually insert them via content resolver.
There is no way the `set` values are being changed. It is immutable set after all. But still somehow, as the execution reaches `insert` function it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`
NOTE: The first iteration went smooth. It's the second one that causes the crash.

Please can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

```
suspend fun unhideSelectedFiles(files: Set<MyFile>, address: String? = null): Flow<UIEvent> = flow {

    val context = App.getContext()
    files.forEach { currentFile ->
        Log.i(TAG, "unhideSelectedFiles: currentFile: ${currentFile.name}")

        if (currentFile.currentPath.isBlank()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unhideSelectedFiles: ${currentFile.name} does not contain a current path")
            return@forEach
        }
        val collection =
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
            }else{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }

        val contentValues: ContentValues =
                ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, currentFile.name)
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, currentFile.mimeType)
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
                    put(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        address ?: currentFile.originalPathWithoutFileName
                    )
                }


        val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)
        uri?.let {
            try {
                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)?.use { outputStream ->
                    val buf = ByteArray(COPY_BYTE_SIZE)
                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(File(currentFile.currentPath))

                    var len: Int
                    while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
                    }
                    outputStream.close()
                    inputStream.close()
                    contentValues.clear()
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)
                    val isUpdated =
                        context.contentResolver.update(it, contentValues, null, null)
                    if (isUpdated > 0) {
                        if (File(currentFile.currentPath).delete()) {
                            emit(UIEvent.FileDone(currentFile))
                            Log.i(
                                TAG,
                                "unhideSelectedFiles: ${currentFile.name} unhidden successfully"
                            )

                        } else {
                            Log.e(
                                TAG,
                                "unhideSelectedFiles: Could not delete the image file from internal storage",
                            )
                            emit(UIEvent.Error("Could not delete ${currentFile.name} from hidden directory"))

                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.e(
                            TAG,
                            "unhideSelectedFiles: something went wrong with the file: ${currentFile.name}",
                        )
                        emit(UIEvent.Error("Something went wrong with the file: ${currentFile.name}"))
                    }

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "unhideSelectedFiles: file: ${currentFile.name}\n\nException: ${e.localizedMessage}",
                )
                emit(UIEvent.Error("Something went wrong: ${e.localizedMessage}"))
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "unhideSelectedFiles: file ${currentFile.name} task completed")


    }
    emit(UIEvent.Finished())
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
2022-03-31 06:47:25.806 13886-6547/com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn, PID: 13886
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:757)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:780)
        at com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn.utils.UtilsKt$unhideSelectedFiles$1.invokeSuspend(Utils.kt:302)
        at com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn.utils.UtilsKt$unhideSelectedFiles$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn.utils.UtilsKt$unhideSelectedFiles$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:212)
        at com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn.viewModels.PhotosViewModel$unhideFiles$1.invokeSuspend(PhotosViewModel.kt:387)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

The function `unhideSelectedFiles(..)` is being called from a ViewModel just like this:

```
    fun unhideFiles(selectedImages: Set<MyFile>, address: String? = null) {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            unhideSelectedFiles(selectedImages, address)
                .collect {
                if (it is UIEvent.FileDone) {
                    repository.deleteImage((it.file as ImageFile).toImageEntity())
                } else {
                    /**
                     * you can show the progress of file by emitting the received flow and catching
                     * it in Fragment and showing dialog/bottomsheet accordingly
                     */

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the exception stacktrace? How do you know the exception is related to `files` variable? BTW, you don't need this function to be `suspend` - it just returns a flow.

Comment: @broot thanks for the comment. I have added the stack trace to question

Comment: What is the 302 line of your `Utils.kt` file? Is it `files.forEach` line? If yes, then the only explanation I see is that you modify `files` by the caller of `unhideSelectedFiles()`. So whoever invokes this function, it passes a mutable set of files and it modifies it after the call. Could you share the code that invokes `unhideSelectedFiles()` and especially what is the source of `files` parameter? Do you store this list of files anywhere and modify it?

Comment: @broot the class ends at line 301. There is no 302 line. The caller functions receives a `set` and passes a `set`. I have added the code for caller function. The file parameter is used widely but is mutable everywhere.

Comment: Maybe you modified this file since getting the stacktrace? The error says the exception occurred at `Utils.kt:302`. Although sometimes these line indicators are in fact misleading. I just try to make sure that we don't look entirely in the wrong direction, because maybe the problem is not related to `files`, but some other collection.

Comment: Also, `Set` is read-only, but that doesn't mean it can't be modified by someone else, who has a mutable reference to the same collection. As you can see `unhideFiles()` got this set of files as its parameter, so we need to move even one level down to see where did it come from. Sorry for all these questions, but I think this can't be solved without asking them :-)

Comment: What if I share this project on GitHub? Would you be able to pull and see where are things getting nasty? I mean it is a lot to ask but it would be a big help for a struggling developer like me.

Comment: Sure, if you can publish it then please do. I'm only afraid that even if I spot the problem, it may not be straightforward to fix. But well, we'll see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243491/discussion-between-waqas-younis-and-broot).